# Additional Attributes of current product

Tags: product, product-attribute

how to get all additional attributes name and value for current product

i wrote below code but its not working

```
    <?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct()
?>
<?php if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?>
<?php endforeach;?>
<?php endif; echo "ssss";?>
```

Comment: Currently an empty tab is displayed in product page if there is no additional attributes. <br >
I want to write an if condition to completely skip showing "Additional Attributes", if it does not have any. <br >
Any help?

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php

     (array) $excludeAttr = array();
     (array) $data = array();
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        $attributes = $product->getAttributes();
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
//            if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && $attribute->getIsUserDefined() && !in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $excludeAttr)) {
            if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && !in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $excludeAttr)) {
                $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

                if (!$product->hasData($attribute->getAttributeCode())) {
                    $value = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('N/A');
                } elseif ((string)$value == '') {
                    $value = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('No');
                } elseif ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'price' && is_string($value)) {
                    $value = Mage::app()->getStore()->convertPrice($value, true);
                }

                if (is_string($value) && strlen($value)) {
                    $data[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = array(
                        'label' => $attribute->getStoreLabel(),
                        'value' => $value,
                        'code'  => $attribute->getAttributeCode()
                    );
                }
            }
        }

    ?>

<?php if($_additional = $data): ?>
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?>
<?php endforeach;?>
<?php endif; echo "ssss";?>
```

Please try this

Answer (score 4):

Reference Amit Bera's answer, I write a simple code example according to my needs, hope it will help someone search the same question.

```
<?php
$additional = array();
$attributes = $_product->getAttributes();
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront()) {
        $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
        if (is_string($value) && strlen($value)) {
            $additional[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = array(
                'label' => $attribute->getStoreLabel(),
                'value' => $value
            );
        }
    }
}
foreach ($additional as $_additional) {
    echo $_additional['label']. ': '. $_additional['value']. '<br>';
}
?>
```

You could edit the `echo $_additional['label']. ': '. $_additional['value']. '<br>';` to custom the **Additional Attributes** display.

If you want more control and filter to the **Additional Attributes**, you could study from the Amit Bera's answer.